# Batch script to enable/check the use this connection dns suffix in dns registration checkbox

Tags: batch-file, dns

I want the code to enable/check the use this connection dns suffix in dns registration check box under the advanced dns settings in tcp/ipv4.

I understand the registry key is located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\NetworkInterfaceID\RegisterAdapterName and that the value must be changed to 1 so I just need you to please put it in batch code for me so I can implement in in the rest of my script.

Thank You

AG Peens

Comment: You will need to use the **reg.exe** command.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\NetworkInterfaceID /t REG_DWORD /v RegisterAdapterName /d 1 /f
```

Don't miss the `/f` switch as it forces the overwrite.

Comment: Thank you ill test it and let you know :)